# How to fix "export: command not found" in CentOS?

Tags: centos, path

I got access to a cluster running CentOS 7, and I installed Miniconda in it.
When I run `conda`, I get `conda: command not found`.

Then I realized that the `export` command does not work, and I cannot add the `miniconda3/bin` directory to PATH.

```
$ export PATH="/home/archisman/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
export: Command not found.
```

I don't have `sudo` access.

When I run `echo $0` it says: csh.

Is there any way to fix this issue? I want to add the directory containing `conda` to PATH so that I can use `conda` without going to that directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, in shells that use the `export` command to set environment variables, it is a shell builtin. So if `export` is not found, you are in a different type of shell.

In your case, `echo $0` indicates that your shell is `csh`, where the equivalent syntax would be

```
setenv PATH "/home/archisman/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

However if you are unfamiliar with `csh`, you will almost certainly find it easier to switch to a more familiar shell such as `bash` or `zsh`.

If `csh` has been set as your *login shell* by a system administrator, then you can likely change that in CentOS *without* `sudo` privileges using the `chsh` command:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

If changing your own login shell in this way is not permitted (because `chsh` is not setuid root on your system, or `/bin/bash` is not listed in `/etc/shells` for example), then the "old school" workaround is to create (or edit, if it already exists) a `~/.login` file and `exec bash` (or `exec zsh`) from there to immediately replace the login shell each time you start one.

Comment: `chsh -s /bin/bash` does not allow me to change shell. The other option works. An alternative is to execute bash in `.cshrc`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi doing it from `~/.cshrc` may have unintended consequences if you need to use a non-login csh at any point

Comment: It’ll break graphical logins, for sure.  I saw that a lot at a job where the default shell was csh and was generated from LDAP.  There are ways to make it work, you just need to pass the parameters to the new shell.